# List.Remove() not working when removing this thread

Tags: java

So I'm working on a server that handles a few commands and one small problem is trying to remove the list of active clients when a user decides to log out. Each client is handled in a thread and once the command is done this active client gets removed however its not removing.

Below is an example of removing an active client, this thread is

```
public class serverHandlerThread implements Runnable
{
    private Socket socket;
    //private BufferedWriter clientOut;
    private ObjectOutputStream toClient;
    private MainServer server;
    private Users user;

    //Constructor
    serverHandlerThread(MainServer server, Socket socket)
    {
        this.server = server;
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    private ObjectOutputStream getWriter()
    {
        return toClient;
    }

    private void deleteClient(serverHandlerThread obj)
    {
        synchronized (server.clients)
        {
            server.clients.remove(obj);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run ()
    {
        try
        {
            //Setup I/O
            toClient = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream fromClient = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            while(!socket.isClosed())
            {
                //If server has received a message
                if(fromClient.available() > 0)
                {
                    //Reads message and objects from client
                    String input = fromClient.readUTF();
                    Object obj = fromClient.readObject();

                    //logger(input);

                    switch (input)
                    {
                        //Logout the user
                        case ".logout":
                            //Set the user to being logged out and print the log
                            user = (Users) obj;

                            deleteClient(this);

                            for (int i = 0; i < server.usersList.size(); i++)
                            {
                                if (user.getUserName().equals(server.usersList.get(i).getUserName()))
                                {
                                    server.usersList.get(i).setLoggedIn(false);
                                    logger(user.getUserName() + " has logged out");
                                }
                            }

                            break;

                        //Push message received to other clients
                        default:
                            logger("Sending message to clients");
                            user = (Users) obj;

                            deleteClient(this);


                            logger("clients size is: " + String.valueOf(server.clients.size()));

                            for (serverHandlerThread thatClient : server.getClients())
                            {
                                ObjectOutputStream thatClientOut = thatClient.getWriter();
                                if (thatClientOut != null)
                                {
                                    thatClientOut.writeUTF(user.getUserName() + ": " + input + "\r\n");
                                    thatClientOut.flush();
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`server` is of type `MainServer` which contains the list of clients and is written as `List<ServerHandlerThread> clients`. `MainServer` calls `serverHandlerThread` when a new client is accepted ie. making the server multithread.

The problem is when the clients requests to logout it should delete the user from the active client list. It doesn't and so when the server tries to push messages to all clients it also tried to write a message to the client who's socket has been closed(user who logged out) and so the server spits out a `broken pipe` error. Any ideas?

***Edit**
More information on the mainServer class, omitted a few things but this should be enough information

```
public class MainServer
{

    //Static variables
    private static final int portNumber = 4444;

    //Variables
    private int serverPort;
    private List<serverHandlerThread> clients;

    /**
     * Very basic logger that prints out
     * the current time and date
     * @param msg used when printing the log
     */
    private void logger(String msg)
    {
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now()+ " " +LocalTime.now() + " - " +msg);
    }

    private List<serverHandlerThread> getClients()
    {
        return clients;
    }

    //Starts the server and begins accepting clients
    private void startServer()
    {
        clients = new ArrayList<>();
        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
            acceptClients(serverSocket);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            logger("Could not listen on port: " + serverPort);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    //Continuously accept clients
    private void acceptClients(ServerSocket serverSocket)
    {
        logger("Server starts port = " + serverSocket.getLocalSocketAddress());
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                //logger("Accepts: " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                serverHandlerThread client = new serverHandlerThread(this, socket);
                Thread thread = new Thread(client);
                thread.setDaemon(true);
                thread.start();

                synchronized(clients)
                {
                    clients.add(client);
                }


            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Accept failed on:" + serverPort);
            }
        }
    }

    public MainServer(int portNumber)
    {
        this.serverPort = portNumber;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MainServer server  = new MainServer(portNumber);
        server.startServer();

    }
}
```

***Edit 2**
So I've made a little method that synchronizes the client list accross all threads and edited the mainServer to do this as-well but the problem persists

```
private void deleteClient(serverHandlerThread obj)
{
    synchronized (server.clients)
    {
        server.clients.remove(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to provide us more information on `Server` class and the way you handle multithread.

Comment: @XetraSu I added that info

Comment: 1. Your code wouldn't compile. 2. You're reading and writing from/to a shared non-thread-safe List from multiple threads, without any kind of synchronization. So that can't possibly work well. This is fundamental multi-threading stuff. You need to read about multi-threading. Buy yourself a copy in "Java concurrency in Practice".

Comment: @JBNizet 1. should compile now 2. I've tried synchronisation but the problem persists

Comment: Just synchronizing the removal is not enough. Every access to that list, reading or writing, must be synchronized. If you iterate on it, the whole iteration must be synchronized. Multi-threading is a complex matter. You can't just try random things. You need to understand all the problems that can occur, and how to avoid them in a safe way. Read "Java concurrency in Practice".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably refactor your code using a *client manager* pattern to avoid the problem you currently have:

- You are managing your clients from N threads, one of which being the server.
- You have access to one list with various form of synchronization which may be lead to synchronization issues because the code is all over.

Given this pattern, here is an example (I used synchronized, but other form of synchronization may work):

```
class ClientManager {
  private final List<Client> clients;

  public ClientManager() {
    this.clients = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public synchronized void add(Client client) {
    this.clients.add(client);
  }

  public synchronized void remove(Client client) {
    this.clients.remove(client);
  }

  public synchronized List<Client> list() {
    return new ArrayList<>(this.clients);
  }

}
```

Both `Client` (`ServerHandlerThread`) and `Server` (`MainServer`) will play the `ClientManager`: my point is that this class is doing all the synchronization work and not the Server/Client.

I use a copy of the list to minimize the lock time (otherwise, client would wait for other thread calling `list()`). This means that a `Client` logout may occurs here when you send your message: you'll need to use a flag (alive, etc) indicating if the Client is still there.

You may also check it in the `sendMessage` and return a status indicating if the message was sent or not.

```
class Server {
  private final ClientManager manager = new ClientManager();

  // register new client
  Client newClient() {
    Client client = new Client(manager);
    manager.add(client);
    return client;
  }

  void sendMessageToAll(String msg) {
    for (Client client : manager.list()) {
      // isAlive returns true except if the client was logged out. 
      // It should probably be synchronized too.
      if (client.isAlive()) {
        client.sendMessage(msg);
      }
    }
  }
}

class Client {
  private final ClientManager manager;

  public Client(ClientManager manager) {
    this.manager = manager;
  }

  public void logoff() {
    manager.remove(this);
  }
}
```

**Edit:** to answer your comment, I added an example of the Client and how server and client use the manager.

> Just to clarify you discuss the client having a play in the client
>   manager which confuses me. My server accepts a client (socket =
>   serversocket.accept() ) and sends this socket to a new thread, this
>   thread handles all communication with the client (messaging and
>   commands). After the thread is started the thread is added to the
>   client list. The problem is in the thread when the client sends a
>   command the thread should run the command then delete itself from the
>   client list (clientlist.remove(this)). Will your solution still work
>   here? Cause you discussion about Client confused me

Briefly, yes.

Simple: you are using a `List`, which is by default not synchronized (you could use a `Vector` or `Collections::synchronizedList` for that). Because you do that in several thread, there are synchronization issues (aka "random effect" :)).

Instead of using directly the list, you should rather use a class dedicated to this usage: that's what the `ClientManager` is for. An object which will manage a list of `Client`.

This has also another advantages: instead of having several `synchronized` blocks across your code, all code are in one place.

Comment: Just to clarify you discuss the client having a play in the client manager which confuses me. My server accepts a client (socket = serversocket.accept() ) and sends this socket to a new thread, this thread handles all communication with the client (messaging and commands). After the thread is started the thread is added to the client list. The problem is in the thread when the client sends a command the thread should run the command then delete itself from the client list (clientlist.remove(this)). Will your solution still work here? Cause you discussion about Client confused me

Comment: This worked great thanks. Turns out my problem was related to deleting the wrong client, but I'm glad to have the understanding of synchronising my threads so I'll be using that moving forward